# promise gives undefined result in callback

Tags: node.js

fileUpload.js

```
var Uploader = require('s3-image-uploader');
var express = require('express');
var config = require('./../config.js');
var Promise = require('promise');

var uploader = new Uploader({
    aws: {
        key: config.awsKey,
        secret: config.awsSecret
    },
    websockets: false
});


exports.fileUpload = function(fileName) {

    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        uploader.upload({
                fileId: 'someUniqueIdentifier',
                bucket: 'quflip',
                source: './public/images/' + fileName,
                name: fileName
            },
            function(data) { // success
                console.log('upload success:', resolve);
                resolve(data);
            },
            function(errMsg, errObject) { //error
                reject(false);
            });
    });
};
```

logintest.js

```
var awsUpload = require('./../config/fileUpload.js');

var userData = function(req, res) {
console.log("true/false" + awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image));
```

Here what is happening is, I am getting undefined value in console.log. So it means that callback is not passing the data. How can I pass the data effectively for further purpose

Comment: From a quick look this seems like you misunderstood the concept of promise and asynchronicity. You'll have to do something like `awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image).then(data =>{console.log("true/false" + data)});`. And you need to return the Promise

Comment: Your `fileUpload` function does not return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your function to actually return the promise then change this:

```
exports.fileUpload = function (fileName) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    });
};
```

to this:

```
exports.fileUpload = function (fileName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        // ...
    });
};
```

Without the `return` statement the promise that you're creating is not going to get returned by your function.

But even then you won't be able to use it like this:

```
console.log("true/false" + awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image));
```

You will have to use something like this:

```
awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image).then(result => {
  console.log("true/false" + result);
});
```

Or this, if you're using `async`/`await` and you're inside `async` function:

```
console.log("true/false" + await awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain to the promise with `.then` and do the log there. First, make sure you `return` the promise

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
```

Then, you can do:

```
var userData = function (req, res) {
  awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image).then(data => {
    console.log("true/false" + data);
  });
}
```

If you are working in an environment that supports `async`/`await`, you can do this a bit more simply:

```
var userData = async function (req, res) {
  console.log("true/false" + await awsUpload.fileUpload(profile_image));
};
```

Keep in mind that this will return a Promise.

I don't see where `profile_image` gets set, though.